# 携帯端末で測定した加速度情報を世界軸座標に変換するには

Tags: android

はじめまして。
携帯端末で測定した加速度情報を世界座標軸に変換したいのですが、
うまく変換できません。

持っている情報は
携帯端末軸でのｘ軸、ｙ軸、ｚ軸の加速度
ｙ軸に対する端末の回転角度Θ
ｘ軸に対する端末の回転角度φ
です。

加速度にsin(theta)をかけてみたりしたのですがどうもきちんと変換されないようです。

どのようにすれば世界座標軸に変換できるのか、ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

--
説明が分かりにくかったため、補足いたします。

やりたいことは
携帯端末Aのｘ軸の加速度と、携帯端末Bのｘ軸の加速度を比較
したいのです。
しかし２台の向きが違うためにそのままでは比較できなく、なんらかの補正をかける必要があると考えています。
この補正の仕方を教えていただきたいのです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 世界座標軸に変換とは具体的にどうしたいのですか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。

携帯端末のｘ軸をワールド座標のｘ軸に変換
携帯端末のｙ軸をワールド座標のｙ軸に変換
携帯端末のｚ軸をワールド座標のｚ軸に変換
したいのです。

具体的に言いますと、２台の携帯端末で加速度情を測定しています。
その２台は角度や向きは違いますが、同時に同じように動かしています。
同じように動かしているので、ある絶対的な座標軸に加速度情報を変換することができれば、２台の端末の加速度はほぼ一致します。
この絶対的な座標軸に世界座標軸を用いたいと考えています。

分かりにくい説明で申し訳ありません。

Comment: 同じように動かすとは加速度センサーが出力する端末ごとの座標に対してですか？それとも二台に共通する座標に対してですか？

Comment: 座標に関して誤解があるようですのでやりたいことから教えていただけますか

Comment: @Shintaro 様 やりたいことは２台の携帯端末で測定した加速度を比較したいのです。
加速度はｘ、ｙ、ｚ軸方向の３つで測っており、そのそれぞれを比較したいです。
ただし２台の携帯端末は角度や向きは違いので、端末の軸をある絶対的な軸に変換する必要があると考えています。 分かりにくい説明で申し訳ありません

Comment: コメントで「絶対的な座標軸に世界座標軸」と書いておられますが、世界座標軸という用語は一般的ではありません（絶対座標系の意味かと思ったのですが違うようですね）。もうすこし一般的な用語を使ってください。

Comment: 部屋に固定した座標，というように読める気がします。たとえば部屋に2台携帯があって、1つの台車の上に乗っているとする。携帯はバラバラの方向を向いているとすると、携帯から見た時の加速度は2つで違うけど、ここでほしいのは部屋の隅に立ってる我々からみた台車の加速度、という感じでしょうか

Comment: @riocampos アカウントマージすることができました。ご迷惑をおかけして申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: @yosh そういうことです！私の代わりに上手に説明していだきありがとうございます。

Comment: 携帯がどちらを向いているかは(ついていれば）コンパスから取れるでしょう。そのベクタを加速度と掛け算して、必要ならGPSから取った世界座標も掛けて最終的な加速度を計算するしかないと思います。しかし、そういったアプリをあまり見かけないのはコンパスがあまりにも低精度でこういった処理に使えないからだと推察しますが。
厳密な世界測位系が必要ないなら、静止しているときの重力加速度を元に自分の現在の向きを計算する手もあるかと思います。これまた、静止しているかどうかはかなり低精度ですが。